# SQL Server CE 4.0 Entity Framework, query runs realy slow (compared with SQL Server CE 3.5)

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm writing a small business Winforms application in C#, .NET 4.0, using Entity Framework to query database.

I used SQL Server CE 3.5 as my database and this specific (exactly the same) query executed really fast (didn't measure it, but I didn't notice any delay). Then I switched to SQL Server CE 4.0 and I tested it on the same query and it needed around 4 seconds to execute.

Am I doing something wrong or maybe SQL Server CE 4.0 wasn't meant to be used in Winforms, or...?

Should I just switch back to SQL Server CE 3.5?

Thank you for your answers and time.

EDIT:

My model is very basic, as I am quite early in the development phase.

[image]

My query is absolutely simple:

```
ObjectQuery<Location> locationsQuery = mainDBContext.Locations;
```

Also the table holds under 10 records.

Comment: Can you **show us** the query and provide relevant info about the table structure (columns, datatypes), any indices you have, and the data contained (number of rows etc.) ?? We can't see your screen, nor can we read your mind - so without any really concrete info, we're left **guessing** - at best.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that where I use SQL CE 4.0, this was my first query, which is why it took so much time.

Ah, well, when you write about your problem it seems to help you.

/me ashamed

Comment: Is this an answer? I can't tell.

Comment: The answer is that the measurement was wrong. Query compilation time was only taken into account when using CE 4.0. Question should be closed.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer for 2 days. I'll also vote for closing.