# Simple entity query using SQL Server CE 4.0 slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm using SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 as my database and using Entity Framework. I have a DataGrid that does some calculations (using test data of 8 columns x 10 rows, calcs performed once per row, so 10 times only).

If I use any Entity query, the calc method is noticeably slower. When I remove them, the result is instant (cannot discern a time lag).

Consider this one line of code:

```
Account a = (from accounts in context.Account select accounts).FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead of doing that, I grabbed the data from `context.Account` and put it into a list BEFORE hitting the method that does the calcs:

```
List<Account> accountsTable = context.Account.ToList();
```

And then replaced the above line of code with this one, that does the same thing except it queries the list and not the entity:

```
Account a = (from accounts in accountsTable select accounts).FirstOrDefault();
```

Using the `List<Account>` method there is NO performance drop.

I understand using the entity will query the database and create some overhead - but using a local DB (i.e. no network issues etc) and 10 rows of data, I would have thought it would be negligable.

I've see this post: [SQL Server CE 4.0 Entity Framework, query runs realy slow (compared with SQL Server CE 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674177/sql-server-ce-4-0-entity-framework-query-runs-realy-slow-compared-with-sql-ser) but that isn't the issue here.

I must be missing something simple - if anyone can enlighten me I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a performance gain when using the following:

```
using System.Linq;
Account a = context.Account.FirstOrDefault();
```

I suspect that your query is resolved first (to a list), then passed to FirstOrDefault.  I believe running `FirstOrDefault` directly will result in your code reading in fewer records, and thus better performance.